# understanding pointers in a function argument

Tags: c, pointers

In the code below, could somebody explain what the second argument is? is it a "constant pointer the data".

Thanks

Comment: No, it's a constant pointer to constant data - effectively an "input only" parameter. The fact that the pointer itself is also constant is somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const uint8_t *const data` essentially means that the function will not be able to update either the `data` parameter or the object it points to .  IOW, you can't set `data` to point to a different object within the function.

In short:

```
const T *p           -- p is writable, *p is not
T const *p           -- same as above
T * const p          -- *p is writable, p is not
const T * const p    -- neither p nor *p are writable
T const * const p    -- same as above
```

**Edit**

Note that any change to `data` wouldn't be reflected in the calling function (unlike any change to `*data`), so why bother making it `const`?  Typically it's because the function body needs to preserve that pointer throughout its execution; IOW, if you accidentally update `data` you'd break something later on in the function.  This is just a way to guarantee that such changes can't happen.

Answer (score 4):

The second argument is a const pointer to a const data.

```
 const uint8_t * const == uint8_t const * const
 uint8_t const * const == const pointer to const uint8_t
```

To help you, think of the backwards reading:

- `int*` - pointer to int
- `int const *` - pointer to const int
- `int * const` - const pointer to int

etc.

So in your example, `const uint8_t *const data` is "data const + pointer of uint8_t const" => a const pointer to const data.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the code is in C or C++, the second argument is a constant pointer to constant data (and the variable name is `data`).  The function is promising that it will at most read, but not write, to the memory pointed at by the `data` parameter.  Under normal assumptions, the type of the data is unsigned bytes.